# How to convert a two dimensional data into three dimensional with third dimension as time with single value?

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

I have daily wind data from quickscat ftp://ftp.ifremer.fr/ifremer/cersat/products/gridded/mwf-quikscat/data/daily
The problem is zonal and meridional winds are two dimensional i.e. they contain only (lon, lat) as dimension not (time, lon,lat) as dimension. File contain all the information about time as variable and as dimension. I tried the copy all the dimension and variable data from input file to an output file but something goes wrong. It copy successfully lat, lon and time but does not copy the values of winds. In source file wind is 2-dimensional, but I want wind in output file as 3-dimensional with time as third dimension.Anyway time dimesion has length=1

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import os
in_path = '2000'
out_path = '2000_new'

files = os.listdir(in_path)
fd=0
for names in files:
   # print(names)
    x_file = os.path.join(in_path,names)
    y_file = os.path.join(out_path,names)
    fd +=1
    i_file = nc.Dataset(x_file, 'r')
    z_w = i_file.variables['zonal_wind_speed'][:,:]
    m_w = i_file.variables['meridional_wind_speed'][:,:]
    y = i_file.variables['latitude'][:]
    x = i_file.variables['longitude'][:]
    t = i_file.variables['time'][:]


    os.system("'rm y_file")
    o_file = nc.Dataset(y_file, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
    latitude = o_file.createDimension('latitude', y.size)
    longitude = o_file.createDimension('longitude', x.size)
    time = o_file.createDimension('time',None)

    var = o_file.createVariable('latitude','f4',('latitude'), zlib=True)
    o_file.variables['latitude'].units = 'degree_north'
    o_file.variables['latitude'].long_name ='latitude'
    o_file.variables['latitude'].axis = 'X'

    var = o_file.createVariable('longitude','f4',('longitude'), zlib=True)
    o_file.variables['longitude'].units = 'degree_east'
    o_file.variables['longitude'].long_name = 'longitude'
    o_file.variables['longitude'].axis = 'Y'

    var = o_file.createVariable('time','d',('time'), zlib=True)
    o_file.variables['time'].long_name = 'time'
    o_file.variables['time'].units = "hours since 1900-1-1 0:0:0"
    o_file.variables['time'].calendar = 'standard'
    o_file.variables['time'].axis = 'T'

    var = o_file.createVariable('u','f4',('time','latitude','longitude'),fill_value=-1.e+23, zlib=True)
    o_file.variables['u'].long_name='zonal wind speed component'
    o_file.variables['u'].units = 'meter second-1'
    o_file.variables['u'].coordinates = 'longitude latitude'
    o_file.variables['u'].time = 'time'


    var = o_file.createVariable('v','f4',('time','latitude','longitude'),fill_value=-1.e+23, zlib = True)
    o_file.variables['v'].long_name = 'meridional wind speed component'
    o_file.variables['v'].units = 'meter second-1'
    o_file.variables['v'].coordinates = 'longitude latitude'
    o_file.variables['v'].time = 'time'


    o_file.variables['latitude'][:] = y
    o_file.variables['longitude'][:] =x
    o_file.variables['time'][:] = t
    o_file.variables['u'] = z_w
    o_file.variables['v'] = m_w





    i_file.close()
    o_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your time dimension does not have length 1, it has unlimited length. If you actually want it to have length 1, you need to use

```
#time = o_file.createDimension('time',None)
time = o_file.createDimension('time',1)
```

instead.
Then, to set all data of the first (and only) time index to your values, use

```
o_file.variables['u'][0] = z_w
o_file.variables['v'][0] = m_w
```

If you do end up saving multiple times in the file, replace the 0 with the appropriate index for the data you are copying in.

Alternatively, because time dimension now has length 1, you could also copy it using `numpy.expand_dims`

```
o_file.variables['u'][:] = np.expand_dims(z_w, 0)
o_file.variables['v'][:] = np.expand_dims(m_w, 0)
```